# Java - BufferedReader not reading characters

Tags: java, file, csv, character, bufferedreader

So below is my code. I am having it read from a csv file with values (each one on a newline)

```
54232 
65 
6564 
6232 
67413 
26
```

completely meaningless but I'm calling a sysout after its read a line and it's returning

��5 followed by newlines

I can however use this arraylist to save the file and it saves it just as before except the first value has some Chinese characters strapped on to the start. I have absolutely no idea.

```
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            lines.add(line);
        }

        buffer.close();

        return lines;
```

Comment: Code is within a try/catch(no exceptions coming up) and is within a function of ArrayList<String> type

Comment: file is a String parameter of the function and it's clearly finding the correct file

Comment: Where are you setting lines?

Comment: What do you mean?  It's in the code

Comment: You have a BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning of the file.

Comment: How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved
There was a BOM in my CSV.

Not used to LibreOffice. Fiddled about with the save settings then it worked just fine